# Horizontal scrolling available depending on what's on screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, web

Let's say I have a webpage like this:

```
<header>...</header>
<body>
  <section id="A">...</section>
  <section id="B">...</section>
  <section id="B2">...</section>
  <section id="C">...</section>
</body>
<footer>...</footer>
```

When the section **B** is beeing viewed I would like to be able to do a horizontal scrolling to see section **B2** but when the other sections are on screen there would be no horizontal scrolling.

How would you guys do that ? Any hints ?

Thanks

Comment: Why not just let #B have `overflow-x:scroll`? It essentially solves your viewport consideration since it has to be in the viewport anyway

Comment: Kind of unclear. Is B2 going to be positioned to the side of B? Why not put B2 inside of B and put a overflow-x scroll on B.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you will understand what I have done reading the comments :)

Result: http://jsfiddle.net/Tymek/8kvk91kz/

My **HTML**:

```
<head></head>
<body>
<article>
<header>…</header>
<section id="A">…</section>
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="pan">
        <section id="B">…</section>
        <section id="B2">…</section>
    </div>
</div>
<section id="C">…</section>
<footer>…</footer>
</article>
</body>
```

**SCSS**:

```
article.fixed {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
article {
    section {
        position: relative;
        padding-bottom: 2em;
        float: left;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .wrap {
        width: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
        position: relative;
        .pan {
            width: 200%; /* <- Space for two sections here */
            position: relative;
            section {
                width: 50%;
            }
        }
    }
    footer {
        padding-bottom: 1em;
    }
}
```

And finally - 24 lines of **js with jquery**:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var h = $(window).height(),
        pan = $(".pan").width()/2,
        offset = Math.abs(h - $(".wrap").height()) / 2,
        start = $(".wrap").offset().top - offset,
        stop = start + pan;
    $("body").css("height", $("body").height() + pan + "px");
    $("article").addClass("fixed"); // Taking control over scroll
    $(window).scroll(function(e){
        var scroll = $(this).scrollTop();
        if(scroll < start){ // Above horizontal section
            $("article").css("margin-top", 0-scroll);
            $(".pan").css("margin-left", 0);
        } else {
            if(scroll <= stop){ // Scrolling horizontally
                $("article").css("margin-top", 0-start);
                $(".pan").css("margin-left", 0-scroll+start);
            } else { // Below horizontal section
                $("article").css("margin-top", 0-scroll+pan);
                $(".pan").css("margin-left", 0-pan);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

I re-calculated scroll.

Comment: Hey, thanks this looks good but this is not really want I wanted. I want to be able to scroll the entier page so that only B2 would be visible. Like I said in a comment to @Arrowsmith I have seen some webistes do that but maybe be they were in flash

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom Scrolling Path for the website using Scroll Path Plugin.

Here is a Link : http://joelb.me/scrollpath/

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you want to do is lay out your sections in a grid like this:

A  (blank)
B  B2
C  (blank)

If that is the case you should add CSS for B2 so it is relatively positioned to the right and put both B and B2 inside a <div> to keep them together at the same height in the document.  You have to reorder the sections a bit to make it flow right.  See below.

```
<section id="A">...</section>
<div>  
  <section id="B2" style="float:right">...</section>
  <section id="B">...</section>
</div>  
<section id="C">...</section>
```

You will also have to set the width of sections A, B, and C so they are the full width of your reading area.  This way B2 falls outside the reading area and you can scroll.
 
Note: The horizontal scroll will always be there.  There will just be a blank area to the right if you are near A or C.  If this is not good enough you will need to use Javascript to hide and show the B2 section when needed.

Comment: Thats the thing, I don't want the blank areas. I want to be able to scroll only if there is something on the right. I have seen some websites do that, one of them was probably using flash, but an not sure for the others (didn't seem they were).

Comment: Then add display:none in the B2 style and use javascript to show the section when B comes into view (or whenever you deem best) and similarly hide that section when B is scrolled out of view.